# Getting incorrect public key from certificate using X509_get_pubkey

Tags: c++, openssl, x509

I'm currently writing a system in C++ which stores X509 certificates. The system can then be queried by giving it an email address, it will then return the public key from the X509 certificate associated with that email address.

My problem is that the system is returning a public key that my crypto system is reading as invalid (I'm using jsencrypt).

My testing certificates are generated using the following commands (generate a key first then the certificate):

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -x509 -key key.pem -new -x509 -out cert.pem -days 365
```

The C++ back-end then reads in the PEM file to get a X509 object. To grab the public key on the system: I use the following code:

```
RSA* Certificate::getPublicKey()
{
    EVP_PKEY* pkey = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
    RSA* rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    return rsa;
}
```

The system will return a public key that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEApMyUxuYFmaWa76iiHbEKsH58k1qwtfg19ank8E57W8WCBva/qW9K
5HRR5oGetDimlf9ni9yZZV5dQFSQmEF0tBuk1QvAMJNPrLFAfvI0GqpHD/8xUgLG
DLVEjSx15eTV9Y31x4iv8iHYYo5BJ4QnlPt2Xj5hvEx2K4VD1uWNJT38gGgoik37
Atz4sEDJ0VNXnJTMKr2PlVEvW7OoRqT8/LlsWygUqqBDOFcJpCVehCxwdbDTgOfn
lVWFUSXWphjmERST06b20M2HjFOLOH7GeMuvApYzuRahZjuKqEdK1c10XC/VRJ4M
g4MePO7JqfTlEfX/VeNgp5aD7OVGQsl2swIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

However, this isn't considered valid by the crypto library I'm using in my front-end, jsencrypt. When I examined the test certificate(s) that I'm generating along with jsencrypt's documentation and examples, I noticed that something wasn't right with the key returned by the system using X509_get_pubkey()

For instance, when I run the following commands on the key and certificate PEM files to retrieve the public key...:

```
openssl rsa -pubout -in key.pem -out keyPub.pem
openssl x509 -inform pem -in cert.pem -pubkey -noout > keyPub.pem
```

In both instances, the contents of keyPub.pem was:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApMyUxuYFmaWa76iiHbEK
sH58k1qwtfg19ank8E57W8WCBva/qW9K5HRR5oGetDimlf9ni9yZZV5dQFSQmEF0
tBuk1QvAMJNPrLFAfvI0GqpHD/8xUgLGDLVEjSx15eTV9Y31x4iv8iHYYo5BJ4Qn
lPt2Xj5hvEx2K4VD1uWNJT38gGgoik37Atz4sEDJ0VNXnJTMKr2PlVEvW7OoRqT8
/LlsWygUqqBDOFcJpCVehCxwdbDTgOfnlVWFUSXWphjmERST06b20M2HjFOLOH7G
eMuvApYzuRahZjuKqEdK1c10XC/VRJ4Mg4MePO7JqfTlEfX/VeNgp5aD7OVGQsl2
swIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This is considered valid and can be used successfully by the crypto library on the front end.

Looking at the two outputs, the C++ OpenSSL API call is returning a slightly shorter PEM output, it's missing the first 32 characters. Apart from that, the two outputs are identical.

My question is: what is happening here? Why is X509_get_pubkey() returning a truncated output? How can I retrieve the correct public key programmatically?

Comment: I suspect that you need to return `pkey` object, instead of `rsa`, which in turn is just raw public key value with public exponent, while you need a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` object which is (apparently) in the `pkey` variable.

Comment: Great! That fixed it. I suspected that I had misunderstood OpenSSL's API. Such a simple fix for what I thought was a complicated problem.

Cheers!